# How to set a drop down in a tapestry grid

Tags: tapestry

```xml
<t:grid t:id="selectedListGrid" t:source="selecteditemlist"
    row="item" rowsPerPage="5" inPlace="true" >
    <p:sizecell>
        <select t:model="sizeOption" t:value="1"/>
    </p:sizecell>
```

here is a part of my TML file and following is the place where I set the model. My grid is not inside a form, and the drop down is empty. Any siggetions?

```java
@Property
static final private String[] sizeOption = new String[] {"1","2","3","4"};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You forgot the Tapestry namespace for your select component. Use `<t:select ... />`.
2. It won't work without an enclosing form component.